# OpenCV camera just showing black output

Tags: python, windows, opencv, webcam

I am following these tutorials http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#display-video and trying to capture video from camera. Although the code functions properly, but it doesn't show anything except black screen on the frame window. I don't know why is this happening.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if cap.isOpened() == 0:
        cap.open(0)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have read in some posts that OpenCV might not be supporting my camera. So i don't know what is happening exactly?

Comment: works fine on my system ! It shows a gray live capture in the frame.. try re-installing opencv maybe it can do something

Comment: @VipulSharma  - is it clearly showing you a video i.e. your webcam video as grayscale and are you using 32-bit or 64-bit python and numpy

Comment: yes it shows clear grayscale video .. and I am using 64-bit python and numpy on linux

Comment: @VipulSharma guess i should switch to Linux, even my friend didn't face any problem on Linux. Also can you tell me any tutorial from where i can install those in linux.

Comment: for linux get numpy by "sudo apt-get install python-numpy" and opencv by "sudo apt-get install python-opencv" otherwise installation procedure is provided in the official documentation

Comment: @VipulSharma you are the hero. If you don't mind can you share your email-id or contact number with me please. Since, i have a delay in my project because of lack of knowledge of opencv and linux

Comment: vipul.sharma20@gmail.com contact : 8827931450

Comment: try a different camera id, check in skype to see camera working and how many device and what order you have for video